# How to make Mathematica less than 100 million not output by scientific counting

Tags: output-formatting

I want the result of `1200000000*0.001` to be `1200000`.

[image]

But Mathematica's output is in the form of scientific counting.

How can I make numbers larger than `1.*10^-8` and smaller than `1.* 10^9` output by scientific counting every time in Mathematica?

For example, for the number `1.231456785*10^6`, I want the output to be `1231456.785` every time. It's better to save the settings to the configuration file.

Comment: Look into [ScientificNotationThreshold](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ScientificNotationThreshold.html)

Comment: @GustavoDelfino Thank you for your comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many ways to do this. You could always do

```
   $PrePrint = AccountingForm;
   1200000000*0.001
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or, if you can change the number of digits

```
   $PrePrint = AccountingForm[#, 30] &;
   1.231456785*10^6
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Look up also number formating.

```
 1.*10^-8
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
 1.*10^9
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: For this number, the result of this code does not meet the requirements.
`Rationalize@1.231456785*10^6`

Comment: Check carefully the precedence of the operations *Mathematica* applies in evaluating `Rationalize@1.231456785*10^6`.  It's not clear whether the failure to meet requirements you identify is genuine, or a misunderstanding.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I can use the following settings to meet the needs, but after shutting down and restarting MMA, this setting will not work. How can I save it to the configuration file for permanent effect.
`$PrePrint = 
  ScientificForm[If[10^-5 < # < 10^6, #, N[#]], 15, 
    ExponentFunction -> (If[-6 < # < 6, Null, #] &), DigitBlock -> 4, 
    NumberSeparator -> " "] &;`